# Advanced Filter does not recognize blanks returned by a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Advanced Filtering in Excel to quickly filter through set criteria. I have determined the 'criteria range' and recorded a working macro. When I run the macro without any criteria in the 'criteria range' the macro returns the whole underlying database, which is exactly what should happen.

However, when I insert formula's in the 'criteria range' that return blanks when the set criteria is blank, the macro does not recognize the cell as being blank i.e. it returns nothing.

My question is: how to get Excel to recognize the cell as being blank, thus returning the total underlying dataset, by the formula inserted in the 'criteria range'?

Recorded macro:

```
Sub Filter()

    Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("Interface!Criteria"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("Interface!Extract"), Unique:=False
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub
```

Formula inserted into the 'criteria range':

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"","<="&D4)
```

Thanks in advance,

Hieronymus5

Comment: what is actually in D4? is there a formula or a manually edited value? If there is a formula it isn't actually a blank cell

Comment: Hi datatoo! D4 is actually blank. However, after some experimenting I find that the problem is caused by '=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"","<="&D4)'. Its not so much `D4` but its the cell containing '=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"","<="&D4)´ that´s problematic, since Excel does recognize this cell as being blank (eventhough the function returns ""). So this question comes down to: is there a way in which I can replace the "" by another operator so that Excel can recognize the cell as being empty?

Comment: maybe     =IF(D4="","","<="&D4) will work for you

Comment: No thats basically the same thing as ISBLANK(D4). The problem is really with Excel not recognizing the criteria range being blank due to the cell containing `=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"","<="&D4)`, rather than actually being blank. Thank you for the effort though!

Comment: The formula results are different the isblank version returns <= the other returns nothing

Comment: Nope, the ISBLANK(D4) version returns "" when blank. The core issue is that 'criteria range' does not recognize a cell containing "" as being blank.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are correct and the formula result is not going to work

Perhaps check D4 in the vba and write a blank value, rather than using a formula
If =Range("Interface!Criteria") were Range E1:E2

```
  If Range("D4") = "" Then Range("E2") = "" Else Range("E2") = "<=" & Range("D4")`
```

'then your filter

Answer (score 0):

First of all many thanks to everyone trying to help me with the issue.

Having said that, for me the solution was actually quite easy. The main reason I wanted to have the criteria range blank, was to force the Advanced filter to return all data in the underlying dataset.

However, the criteria range doesn't *need* to be blank for the filter to return all data, one could also force Excel to return all values *except a specific value*.

If you choose this specific value to be some gibberish that's not anywhere in your underlying dataset it will return the full data.

So in my case I replaced `=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"","<="&D4)` by `=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"<>TEST","<="&D4)`. The latter formula with "<>TEST" returns all data *not equal to TEST*. TEST is a value that doesn't exist anywhere in my dataset.

I haven't tried the solution provided by datatoo.